# Is it possible to use Picture in Picture (PIP) mode with Custom Tabs?

Tags: android, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

When opening a YouTube link in an activity with a `WebView` I don't get `Chromecast` and full screen icons. To get those, I seem to have to open the YouTube link in a Custom Tab and that works fine but then **I'm unable to enter PIP mode** since I cannot override `onBackPressed()` like when I host my own `WebView` with the YouTube video.

Is it possible to open a YouTube video inside an Android app with fullscreen button, `Chromecast` button and then enter PIP mode when pressing back?

To me it doesn't look that way and the Android YouTube API seems very outdated so didn't even look at that one: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/